# loop through checkedListBox items without the select all item

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

I want to get the items from a `checkedListBox` into a `List<>`, but without the select all/ deselect all (first checkbox)..can't figure it out how to not add the first item..
this is the code:

```
foreach (string s in checkedListBoxDepts.CheckedItems)
{
      if (checkedListBoxDepts.SelectedItems.IndexOf(s) == 0)
          continue;
      list.Add(s);
}
```

then I take the items and put in another list to avoid errors:

```
foreach (string s in list)
{
    list2.Add(s);
}
```

but still the select all is loaded...help

Comment: show ur markup of checkedBoxList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach (var s in checkedListBoxDepts.CheckedItems)
{
      if (checkedListBoxDepts.IndexOf(s) == 0)
          continue;
      list.Add(s.ToString());
}
```

Comment: why typecast in each iteration isn't it better to use 'string s'  in place of var s in foreach ?

Comment: That's is not casting and is implicit typing. It means that the compiler figures the type for the variable out by itself.

Comment: At home this code dont work, must be like this:
checkedListBoxDepts.SelectedItems.IndexOf

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (string s in checkedListBoxDepts.CheckedItems)
{
  if (checkedListBoxDepts.SelectedItems.IndexOf(s) == 0)
      continue;
  list.Add(s);
}
```

after that remove first item from list

```
list.removeat(0);
```